# Alternative to "mensch"

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, words

When talking to a Torah Scholar, if you want to say that they are a "mensch" (as well), is there a better word that fits with a more Haredi/Litvish hashkafah?

I am asking as (it seems to me) a more secular Jew would find the word "mensch" a compliment, but for a Torah Scholar it does not quite seem to fit the idea of a mensch who derives part of his menschlikeit from his Torah knowledge and middot.

Comment: @DanF I think it's more a question about Jewish cultural norms (within a particular community).

Comment: @DanF: I have edited my question.  Is that better?  Did I understand correctly the edit you wanted?

Comment: I'm fine with the edits, though, I don't quite agree for the premise. I think that the term "mentech" is generic menaing "a good upright, straightforward, honorable person". Certainly, that's what a rav is or should be. (Occasionally, some are **not** menches.) And a rav who is a mentch, is humble enough not to seek anything more, anyway. The answer, below, is a means of showing him extra honor, which is also appropriate, but, perhaps, unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about "*[ben torah](http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/words/57)*"? (See e.g. [here](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/what-does-it-take-to-be-a-ben-torah), [here](http://etzion.org.il/en/what-does-it-mean-be-ben-torah-part-1-2), and [here](http://matzav.com/rav-shteinman-the-tachlis-is-to-be-a-ben-torah/).)

You could also try "*baal middos*".

Comment: Or "_baal midos tovos_", since "_baal midos_" can also mean "person of size".

Comment: @msh210 no, that would be a "person of sizes." _baal midda_ might mean "person of size"

Answer (score 3):

Historically, the ideal Jew in most of Eastern Europe was praise as an "*ehrlicher Yid*". Unlike the modern favorite of "*frum*", the implications of *ehrlich* revolve more around those *mitzvos* related to honesty, kindness, in addition to meaning observant as a whole.

“*Frum*” descends from the German “*fromm*“, meaning pious or devout. In pre-war Yiddish, usage appears to have varied widely. On the one hand, those who named their daughters “Fruma” clearly thought being *frum* as complementary. On the other, there was an idiom, or as Rav Aharon Kotler often put it, “*Frum iz a galech; ehrlich iz a Id* — the town priest is ‘pious’, a Jew is refined.” I also heard the first part from grandparents of that same generation, “*frum iz a galech*“.  Admittedly, both data points are from Lithuanian Iddish. (In Lithuanian dialect, the language is called אידיש not יידיש; similarly you may have seen in the quote from R' Aharon -- a Jew is א איד, not א ייד.)

Anyway, I think "*ehrlach*" and "*ehrlachkeit*" are what you are looking for. At least for this sentence, and hopefully as a life-goal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the term **chassid** would also be appropriate. I'm not talking about its meaning as used today, which tends to mean a person with a long beard, payot, and wearing some type of black robe and a shtreimel on Shabbat and Yom Tov, etc. I'm talking about its original meaning as used in many places in the Mishnah and Gemarah.

See [Pirkei Avot 5:10 and 11](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) as examples. One says that someone who says "What's mine is yours and what's yours is yours" is a Chassid. Another says that someone who does not get angry easily and is easily appeased is also a chassid.

If this rav, demonstrates such behavior, which I hope he does, calling him a chassid is a huge compliment.

Comment: One famous person who had this 'title' was the Vilna Gaon AKA the Chasid from Vilna. (Ironic?)

Comment: @DanF:  While I think this would have been a great suggestion in the past, nowadays the term chassid has the complete connotation of a Chassid.